# fetch() Отправляет запрос много раз

Tags: vue.js, request, vuex, fetch

Здраствуйте делаю админ панел на Vue. Использую fetch() в Vuex - actions. Делаю запрос с локалхоста на другой сервер. Первый запрос отправляеться 2 раза. Второй запрос отправляеться 4 раза. Третий - 8 раз. И так продолжаеться. 2 дня испробовал много чего. Никак не могу решить. Спасибо.
[image: Форма отправки (логин)]
[image: Метод кокторый срабатывает при submit]

[image: Первый запрос]

[image: Второй запрос]

Comment: Очевидно, что проблема не с самим fetch, а с каким-то обработчиком события, который сам себя повторно навешивает)

Comment: a**pp**lication/json

Comment: В первый раз 2 запроса — вероятно, один из них - это preflight CORS запрос с глаголом OPTIONS

Comment: Да проблема не с fetch(). Переписал на axios. То же самое. А насчет preflight - не думаю. Потому что запросы после первого тоже умножаються на 2. Думаю проблема связана с VUE. Но в интернете ничего не нашел

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что в данный момент в вашем вопросе недостаточно данных, чтобы вам помочь? Приведите [mcve]

Comment: А какие данные еще нужны?

Comment: Соберите минимальное vue приложение, в котором вот так дублируются запросы. По хорошему, если замените fetch на console.log, факт дублирования останется.

Comment: Ткните на самый первый запрос /login, он точно не OPTIONS?

Answer (score 1):

> @vp_arth: Очевидно, что проблема не с самим fetch, а с каким-то обработчиком события, который сам себя повторно навешивает)

`onSubmitLogin` - обработчик события.
В нём при каждом срабатывании на `this.fv` навешиваются дополнительные обработчики событий `core.form.valid` и `core.form.invalid`..
После срабатывания они никуда не деваются, а при следующем клике на submit к ним добавляется пара новых обработчиков. При этом в каждом обработчике `valid` выполняется http запрос.

Эти обработчики нужно навешивать вне обработчика submit, либо реализовывать паттерн `.once()`, который отписывается при первом же срабатывании.

---

FormValidation.validate возвращает Promise, поэтому можно вообще не пользоваться его событийной системой:

```
this.fv.validate()
  .then(status => {
        // status can be one of the following value
        // 'NotValidated': The form is not yet validated
        // 'Valid': The form is valid
        // 'Invalid': The form is invalid
  if (status === 'Valid') {
    return fetch('...');
  }
});
```

Comment: Да вы правы. Убрал валидацию и тепер работает 1 раз. Можете написать где смогу найти информацию про паттерн .once() . Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: Нафиг это once(кстати, он может уже есть, я просто не в курсе, что такое this.fv у вас, попробуйте поменять .on на .once), Лучше просто уберите оба .on куда нибудь в инициализацию компонента.

Comment: Нашёл, там нету .once. Можно просто вызывать .off внутри обработчика)

Comment: Да есть .off(). Но как его использовать и что передавать в параметры?

Comment: Забейте и используйте Promise, который возвращает validate()

Comment: Ок. Огромное вам спасибо. Удачи.